# bundle size increase after changing to standalone component

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have updated our Angular application to version 16 and also converted all the components into standalone components. However, after converting them into standalone components, the bundle size has significantly increased by 4X. I tried to move common imported modules to the parent component, but that did not work, and it caused the build to fail. Is there any way to keep the build size small or maintain it at the same level as the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience bundle size is a constant thorn in the side of Angular Developers. Here's some pointers I've picked up.

**1. Use modules with their own routing**

This enables you to separate them and not include them in the "main" bundle (e.g. not in the app.module.ts).

For example a "Products" component has it's own module and also imports this: -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ProductComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductRoutingModule { }
```

If your application has natural functionality that is only required in certain areas this will lazy load the required modules and significantly reduce the initial bundle size.

**2. Use an analysis tool to look at the bundle sizes**

```
ng build --configuration production --stats-json
webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json
```

**3. If applicable separate your vendor libraries**

In the angular.json use this line in your production build: -

```
"vendorChunk": true
```

If nothing else this gives a better look when analysing the bundles and the relative sizes of your modules without the size of libraries included.